# How to create a child object in Serializer Django Rest?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a task, I need to return this json object here:

```
  {
    "id": "99999999",
    "point": "11111111",
    "name": "some name",

    "quantity": {
      "needed": "10",
      "done": "2",
    },

  }
```

I must have the `quantity` field as a child object, but in the Django model `quantity_needed` and `quantity_done` must not be child objects. Here is the code:

```py
# model.py
class NeedModel(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(ArticleModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    point = models.ForeignKey(PointModel, verbose_name="Hospital", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity_needed = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    quantity_done = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I tried to change this using the `to_representation` method, here's what my code looks like:

```py
# serializer.py
class NeedsSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = NeedModel
        fields = ('id', 'point')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(NeedsSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)

        data['name'] = instance.article.name

        data['quantity'] = {
           'needed': instance.quantity_needed,
           'done': instance.quantity_done,
        },


        return data
```

**But as a result, I get a `quantity` field with a list that contains the object. How to get rid of this list?**

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "point": 4,
    "name": "Бинт гіпсовий 20см х2,7м",

    "quantity": [
        {
            "needed": 12,
            "done": 0
        }
    ],

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the answer is very simple. You need to create the dictionary as it should and then use the `update` method

```py
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(NeedsSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)

    data['name'] = instance.article.name

    q = {'quantity': {
       'needed': instance.quantity_needed,
       'done': instance.quantity_done,
    }}

    data.update(q)
    return data
```

And here is the result:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "point": 2,
    "name": "Захисний костюм",       

    "quantity": {
        "needed": 1000,
        "done": 40
    }
},
```